# Uploading SSL certificates TO IAM

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services

I have 4 certificates which i received from CA (SSL) :

> Root CA Certificate - 123.crt
>
> Intermediate CA Certificate - 456.crt
>
> Intermediate CA Certificate - 789.crt
>
> Your PositiveSSL Certificate - 654.crt

I have generated `circuit.pem` **-private key** and `csr.pem` through which I got these certificates.

Now, i want to upload these certificates to IAM using

```
    aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name certificate_object_name --certificate-body file://public_key_certificate_file --private-key file://privatekey.pem --certificate-chain file://certificate_chain_file
```

[AWS -Working with Server Certificates](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/InstallCert.html)

But I am not able to gauge which is my server certificate and how can I upload my all certificates.

Please help me with the above command for my above certificates.

**I tried :**

```
    aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name MyServerCertificate --certificate-body file://www_advisorcircuit_com.crt --private-key file://circuit.pem --certificate-chain file://COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
```

I am getting this error:

```
A client error (InvalidClientTokenId) occurred when calling the UploadServerCertificate operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

Answer (score 12):

I have to say, getting this to work was a huge pain in the ass.  Basically you are missing the user configuration details.  You have to create a user on Amazon using the IAM service here https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home.  Pay attention to what your region is in the url, you'll need that later.  So create a user, attach a policy (I attached AdministratorAccess), "Create Access Key", download credentials for the user and use them to run:

```
$ aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [None]: AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
Default region name [None]: us-west-2
Default output format [None]: json
```

Some caveats on getting the certificate install command to work.  Make sure the file's have readable permissions....I think I specified 664.  I specified the .pem extension on all the files...I believe AWS prefers the old school style key files, so I had to run

```
openssl rsa -in my_key.key -text > new_key.pem
```

Comment: AWS is by far the most convoluted system I have ever worked with. I thought Azure was bad.

Answer (score 7):

An additional hint (because that's what happened to me)

Run `echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `echo $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` to check if these ENV variables are set.

No matter what you pass to `aws configure`, the ENV variables will override it.

[Configuration Settings and Precedence](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#config-settings-and-precedence)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This is tricky even you have configured all IAM access to a user and then trying to upload certificate using their access keys.

I got this problem many times. Here is how I solved it.

- When User is not having required IAM access like Upload Server certificate etc. -> You need to make sure that user has the right access, Maybe try after giving Full IAM access to the user.
- Of Course, the region and the other user details should be correct as discussed in previous answers.
- Was trying with an older session terminal(This terminal was running for more than 24 hours) -> Relaunch the terminal and try the same command. Yes, I observed this issue twice. I simply relaunched the terminal and performed the same command and it worked.

**Command with absolute path:**

```
*aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name mycertificate --certificate-body file:///Users/raushan/Downloads/com/certificate.pem --private-key file:///Users/raushan/Downloads/com/private_key.pem --certificate-chain file:///Users/raushan/Downloads/com/CertChain.pem*
```