# Terraform AWS Provider Error: The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, token, terraform-provider-aws

I have been using Terraform to deploy one pipeline on AWS successfully for the past few years. However, recently, my colleague and I have encountered an issue when running `terraform plan`.
We are consistently getting the following error message:

`Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan. Error: validating provider credentials: retrieving caller identity from STS: operation error STS: GetCallerIdentity, https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: 334b70c6-9e8f-47b9-a317-26e95aebb0f8, api error InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.`

We've tried several troubleshooting steps, including:

1. **Testing on Different AWS Accounts**: We tested the same Terraform configuration on different AWS accounts, but the issue persists.
2. **Updating Terraform and Providers**: We've updated our Terraform version and the provider plugins using the `terraform providers` command to ensure we are using the latest versions.
3. **Trying different identification**: We've tried to connect by setting AWS environment variables (Short-term credentials) with the EXPORT command. We also tried using the AWS CLI and changing our keys there. Indeed we also to hard code our key in the main.tf code but still the same issue arise.
4. **Simplified Configuration**: We even tried deploying the simplest possible architecture as a test, but the error still occurs. Here is the simplified Terraform configuration we are testing with:

```
provider "aws" { 
       region     = "us-east-1" 
       access_key = "XXXX" 
       secret_key = "XXXX" 
} 

resource "aws_instance" "example" { 
      ami           = "ami-06e2b86bab2edf4ee" 
      instance_type = "t2.micro" 
}
```

We would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or solutions to resolve this issue and get back to deploying our infrastructure as usual. Not sure if something changed in the last few months with AWS roles and restriction.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Had you checked if the user linked to the credentials have an attached role which allow `sts:GetCallerIdentity` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I resolve the error "The security token included in the request is invalid" when running aws iam upload-server-certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582318/how-can-i-resolve-the-error-the-security-token-included-in-the-request-is-inval)

Comment: @STerliakov, THanks for the link but this didn't help. I played around with all the advices especially the one about AWS CLI and the credential file but nothing. 
I am guessing that something changed in AWS but I can't find out what

Comment: @DaniloCacace, thanks for the advice. So I checked and I couldn't find the sts:GetCallerIdentity rights in any roles. After some googling I find out that this doesn't need any permissions (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetCallerIdentity.html). Am I missing something ?

Comment: @NKLSNKLS From the error message seem clear that Terraform is trying to do this operation, try to add this action in the policy statement just as a test to see if it works or it return a different error

Comment: @NKLSNKLS Can you also put the environment variable TF_LOG to TRACE or DEBUG to see better what Terraform is trying to do https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/internals/debugging

Comment: @NKLSNKLS I also found this, can be helpful https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/28870