# Getting error "Get-LMFunctionList : The security token included in the request is invalid" when using PowerShell function Get-LMFunctionList

Tags: powershell, aws-lambda

I am trying to run the PowerShell command `Get-LMFunctionList -Region "eu-west-1"` after importing the module `AWS.Tools.Lambda`. I am using PowerShell version 5.1 and AWS.Tools.Lambda version 4.1.530.

When I run the command I get the error message

```
Get-LMFunctionList : The security token included in the request is invalid
```

If I try to run the equivalent command via the AWS CLI (i.e. `aws lambda list-functions --region eu-west-1`) everything runs fine and I get a list of functions with their details. So it looks like this is specific to the PowerShell command.

I have tried all the suggestions listed in the Stack Overflow article [How can I resolve the error "The security token included in the request is invalid" when running aws iam upload-server-certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582318/how-can-i-resolve-the-error-the-security-token-included-in-the-request-is-inval) but none of these answers have solved my issue.

- I created a new access key and secret key and added them to the credentials file
- I regenerated the `.aws\credentials` file using the command `aws configure`
- I have restarted the session multiple times
- I am not using a session key to connect
- It is not a profile problem because it works when I use the AWS CLI
- There were no cache files at `~\.aws\cli\cache\`

Comment: The token is not the certificate, it is the Authentication.  AWS is using a two step authentication.  Step 1 Is to make a http request and get a token/cookie.  Step 2 is to make a second http request to make a query using the token.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/aws/aws-azure-ad-security.  Here is how you do it with Powershell https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/specifying-your-aws-credentials.html

Comment: I don't understand your answer @jdweng. When I read the article https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/specifying-your-aws-credentials.html it tells me that the module and PowerShell will use the `C:\Users\username\.aws\credentials` file. This file on my machine is set up correctly (which I know because I can run commands from the aws cli directly).

Comment: Credentials is a login with a username and password.  Authentication is when you make an HTTP connection to a webpage that allows access to the server/webpage.  You first need to get a Authentication Token using the Credentials.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the default profile included in the `.aws\credentials` file contained the correct credentials but the default profile that has been created in the `AWS SDK` (i.e. stored in the `NetSDKCredentialsFile` store) had not been updated.

As described in the article [Using AWS Credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/specifying-your-aws-credentials.html) shared by @jdweng the AWS SDK takes priority over the shared credentials in the `.aws\credentials` file.

In my particular case, I had a default profile created in the `.aws\credentials` file and a default profile created in the AWS SDK store, which was outdated. However because the AWS SDK credentials were taking priority, only the out-of-date credentials were being used.

I could see the default profiles created in both stores when I ran the command `Get-AWSCredential -ListProfileDetail`.

The solution was removing the default profile from the AWS SDK using the `Remove-AWSCredentialProfile -ProfileName default` command. After that, the correct credentials in the shared credentials file were used.

Note that I tried to update the credentials in the AWS SDK and that worked but I found that the region-specific configuration stored in the `.aws\config` was then ignored. So I reverted to using the shared credentials (i.e. all the files in the `.aws\` folder).